# How to make Git ignore changes or elimination of files at a branch?

Tags: git, version-control

Having both typical branches, **`master`** with *A* and *B* files and later create **`dev`** branch:

- I might create new files at `dev` and maybe modify *B* but,
- lets say that either I change or even delete *A*
- When I decide to merge them so `master` might look like `dev`
- **I want the A file (or any other file or folders) to remain the SAME, no matter how the merged branch looks like.**

How can I achieve this?

Would `git reset` or `git revert` help me solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the merge with `--no-commit`.  Once the automatic part of the merge is finished, git stops (the same way it would if it cannot complete the merge itself) and you may now alter the merge result in whatever way you like, including checking out the desired version of file A:

```
git checkout branch -- A
```

or:

```
git checkout --ours -- A
```

(etc).

Once the tree has been adjusted to your satisfaction (if you have automated tests, use them!), `git add` if needed, and `git commit` the result to complete the merge.

(You can automate some or all of this, if you like.)

---

Edit to add example.  Let's say you want to merge `dev` into `master`, but keep `master`'s version of `xyz.html`.  (I removed `xyz.html` in branch `dev`.  I also added file `foo`, and made no other changes.)  Let's also use `--no-ff` to force a real merge.  (Otherwise git may be able to do a fast-forward merge, if branch `dev` is exclusively ahead of `master`.  In this case our `--no-commit` has no effect, since git won't attempt a commit anyway.)

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge --no-ff --no-commit dev
Removing xyz.html
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
$ git checkout master -- xyz.html
```

(You can check out any particular version of `xyz.html`: the above just gets the version from the tip of branch `master`.  Since you are actually *on* branch `master` there are many other ways to spell this; that's just the most explicit I could think of.)

```
$ git status
On branch master
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

    new file:   foo

$ git commit
```

(at this point the editor opens, as with any other commit; writing out the file and exiting produces)

```
[master 9746054] Merge branch 'dev'
$
```

Comment: "Where" (at what branch) should I be when doing either `git checkout branch -- A` or `git checkout --ours -- A`?

Comment: If you are merging `dev` into `master`, you must necessarily be on `master` when you issue the `git merge` command.  This form of `git checkout` (with `--` and paths; you can omit the `--` if and only if the path names do not look like branch names or flags) does not change your current branch, so you will still be on the same branch you are merging-into.

Comment: Hmm can you edit your question and explain quite step by step like with an example? I got bit confused

Comment: Thanks! When should I not and should use the `--no-ff` argument?

Comment: Well, "when" is more detailed than just the one example above, but this is a case where allowing fast-forward means there is no actual merge, so it is in fact required here if the merge would be a non-merge fast-forward.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126297/when-to-use-the-no-ff-merge-option-in-git and the selected answer for more.

Comment: I'm satisfied with your answer, however next time I did a commit and even when I had to pull, I noticed such A files to be "there" again... So I wonder whether I always have to do these git commands

Comment: Every time you merge (and `git pull` is just a script that does `git fetch` followed by `git merge`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/292359/1256452) git does the same thing: find "merge base", diff merge-base with tip of current branch, and diff merge-base with to-be-merged commit.  Then it combines the changes from "to-be-merged" with the changes found in the first diff.  If the first diff makes no changes to file `F` and second makes a change, git "wants to" take the change.  So it depends on what's in these two diffs.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways how to do this:

I. Assuming the file version you wish to keep on *master* is commited.

```
git checkout dev
git add -u                           <--- add tracked files to the commit
git commit -m "my commit"            <--- the new commit
git push                             <--- by default: to origin, but you may explicitly choose

git checkout master         
git log                              <--- check the last commit's hash
git pull dev                         <--- either clean, or merge required
git checkout <hash> file/to/restore  <--- get the master's version of the file
```

II. Create patches of the dev's commits and manually edit them.

```
git format-patch -<how_many> <sha>   <--- note: <sha> is literally there,
// send the patches to server, e.g. scp
// edit the patches, e.g. gedit 0001blabla.patch
git am <patch>                       <-- apply the patch
```

III. Create commits on *dev* excluding the change to the file, push the commits to *master*. Then create a commit on *dev* actually changing the file. As a result, commits on *master* are a subset of *dev*'s.

There are probably tons of other too.

Comment: It'll pull the commits from the dev branch onto the master branch (if it's possible). Similiar to git merge. You may need to resolve the conflicts though

Comment: `git pull` is pretty much just `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, so this will make a merge that removes the file.  You can of course restore the file as shown, and make another commit, or even use `git commit --amend`, but that's kind of the long way around.