# Git: move last commit from branch to master

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket

I have 2 commits: A and B. Both are independent from each other and contain different files. I have 2 branches: `master` and `branch1`:

```
master: A
branch 1: A, B
```

I need to remove `branch 1` and to move commit `B` to `master`. I tried to do that with

`git cherry-pick B`,

but it just copied B into A, while I need it to have the same commit number and - most importantly - to save the comments that are there!

Is there any way? I've looked through different answers and really unsure of what to do with my situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two options, a [merge](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge), or a [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

### Merge

Merging branch1 into master is the simplest operation to understand, and the option I would recommend. However, it will appear as a new commit on the master, **with a different commit id**.

We will take the new commits from branch1 and attempt to merge them into master as a new changeset which we can then commit. This will preserve the history of both branch1 and master.

From the command line, you would execute the following steps:

1) First checkout the branch you wish to merge *into*

```
git checkout master
```

2) Now merge in your branch, using the [--no-ff option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126297/when-to-use-the-no-ff-merge-option-in-git)

```
git merge --no-ff branch1
```

3) You can now delete the old branch if desired

```
git branch -d branch1
```

---

### Rebase

The alternative approach is to perform a rebase.

By rebasing your branch 1 onto master, you will effectively replay the commit history of branch1 onto the master. Afterwards, it will appear as though you had originally checked commit 'b' into master, **preserving your commit id**.

Again, from the command line, you would execute the following steps:

1) First checkout the branch you want to rebase *into*

```
git checkout master
```

2) Now rebase your branch into the master

```
git rebase branch1
```

Note - there are some caveats with rebasing, and if you don't fully understand how it works, it's safer to use a merge instead.

If in doubt - merge, don't rebase.

Comment: Not a problem. It's worth noting, if you drop the --no-ff from the merge command, it will achieve the same thing in your scenario as a rebase. I'm not familiar enough with the repercussions of this though, so perhaps someone else can edit / elaborate.